# OpenCV install on Python 3.6: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, module, pip

I am getting the following error when using `import cv2`:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

My version of Python is 3.6 64 bit. I have downloaded the whl file to install it via pip manually, and have also installed it with `pip install opencv-python` however I still get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

pip outputs `Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\...\python36\site-packages`

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your code use same Python version as pip? (`pip -v` and search for python version)

Comment: Do other modules installed the same way work for you?

Comment: @M.Volf Yes all other modules, tensorflow, numpy, matplotlib all successfully install with that command

Answer (score 2):

Your download must have been corrupted. It happened to me too. Simply uninstall the package and use

`sudo apt-get install python open-cv`

Comment: As you can see from `Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\...\python36\site-packages`, he's using Windows, so `sudo` or `apt-get` is "chinese" for him...

Comment: It is indeed "chinese" for me haha. Would I just reinstall it with the normal `pip install opencv-python` command?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Yes I would recommend you reinstall it as opencv gets corrupted sometimes. It happened a lot to me when I was working on a face recognition project. Try and tell us if it works

Comment: Yep that did the trick! I just reinstalled it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip install -U opencv-python`

Comment: Can you explain the U flag? (from review)

Comment: -U flag is an abbreviation of --upgrade, it will upgrade the existing package (if exists).